# Defining a macro to output a Greek symbol

Tags: fonts, macros, greek

I'm writing a document with *a lot* of Greek letter combinations like [image: $2x^2$]. I'm tired of having to type `\gamma^{\mu}` or similar every time. I wanted to define a macro which would produce the same result. If I wanted the superscript to be bold, I would use:

```
\newcommand{g}[1]{\gamma^{\textbf{#1}}}
```

which produces [image] .
Obviously, I want the superscript to be a Greek letter, however:

```
\newcommand{g}[1]{\gamma^{\#1}}
```

doesn't work. What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\textbf` is for text mode ;-) You want, if at all, `\mathbf{\mu}` And Using `\newcommand{\g}{...}` is not really useful actually, such one - letter - macro names will prove shooting oneself into the foot later on

Comment: Ok, fair enough, the bold font one was only a side example. Also I see your point about this being problematic. But just out of curiosity, how would I make the Greek letter in the superscript?

Comment: you say you get **mu** from your macro but you did not show its use, presumably you used `{mu}` not `{\mu}`

Comment: @JakubKryś: I remember `\mathbf` not useful for greek symbols. You need `\boldsymbol`

Comment: your question seems completely unrelated to defining a macro, without any macro definition if you use `\gamma^{mu}` then you get `mu` in the output, your macro definition just does the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The O.P. 'clarified' below my post. It's about laziness... `\g{mu}` should expand to `\gamma^{\mu}`

Comment: @JakubKryś: Side question: Is `\gamma^\mu` meant for relativistic quantum theory, or the Dirac equation?

Comment: Indeed, I'm writing up proofs of identities for combinations of gamma matrices and 'slashed' 4-momenta, such as `\gamma^\mu \slashed{a} \gamma^\nu \slashed{b} \gamma_\mu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\textbf` is not meant for math mode, so either not useful, doing nothing or will just print another character.

`\mathbf` is useful for Latin letters and numbers only, but not for other math symbols. One way is to use `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath`.

Please do also not use `\newcommand{\g}{...}` (correcting the missing `\` already) -- use 'nice' abbreviations, such as `\gamsup`, standing for `\gamma superscript`.

[image]

In total, using a bold superscript may be typographically doubtful...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\gamsup}[1]{\gamma^{\boldsymbol{#1}}}

\begin{document}


$\gamsup{\mu}$

\end{document}
```

**Sigh**

For the lazy ones...

Use `\boldsymbol{\csname#1\endcsname}` as superscript, this will work even if the macro name does not exist -- it will display `\gamma` only then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\gamsup}[1]{\gamma^{\boldsymbol{\csname#1\endcsname}}}

\begin{document}


$\gamsup{mu}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forget the bold font example, I shouldn't have used it. Let's focus on getting the Greek letter. I can do `\newcommand{\gamsup}[1]{\gamma^{#1}}` and then `\gamsup{\mu}` is going to produce the desired result. But, just out of my curiosity for how the syntax works, what if I wanted the code `\gamsup{mu}` to work (without the \ inside the argument). What would be the corresponding macro?

Comment: @JakubKryś: That's changing the question, apart from being not really an useful approach, just being laziness. See the edit at the bottom...

Comment: That was meant to be my original question, apologies for the confusion. I know it's laziness and your solution is better - I was wondering how to do it the way I described it in the comment above, just for the sake of it.

Comment: @JakubKryś: As I wrote: see at the end of my answer... I don't recommend it, however

Comment: Thanks, lesson learnt. I won't use it, but it's good to know how one _could_ do it.

Comment: @JakubKryś: There's not much you can't do with macros ;-)

Comment: one small thing missing here is *why* `{\#1}` doesn't work.  (because `\#` is the predefined command to typeset a number sign.)  might want to add that for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You want syntax like `\g{\mu}`.

As for getting the symbol you want, in `unicode-math`, you can use any of the math alphabets (such as `\symbfup`, `\symbfit`, or `\mathbf`) or [the macros defined by the package.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)

If you need code that runs on PDFLaTeX, the `isomath` package provides a comprehensive selection of math alphabets that include Greek letters in different styles, with a standardized interface.  In addition to bold upright, it adds new bold italic, sans-serif and sans-serif bold math alphabets, all of which support Greek.  The most compatible command for upright bold math letters is `\mathbold{\mu}`.  However, be aware that there are very few legacy math fonts with unslanted bold Greek letters, and some of them, such as AMS Euler and Fourier, use a non-standard encoding.

You can also use any legacy Greek text font in the LGR encoding with `mathastext`.

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: @Martund Thanks. Fixed now.